# How do I install PHP 5.4.8 on a Win XP workstation?

Tags: php, windows

I am trying to create a MediaWiki site on my WinXP workstation, and need to install PHP 5.4.8.  I have downloaded and unpacked the binaries for PHP, but the install instructions are telling me to "Run the MSI installer and follow the instructions provided by the installation wizard."

Unfortunately there is no MSI file provided in the package!  Am I missing something?  Besides a clue, I mean.

**Edited to add**: I will try to make this clear.  I am not going to be able to work with Apache.

Comment: Try these: **1)** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBo7-Wy0bdM **2)**  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2lczTgePeA **3)**  http://forums.iis.net/t/1047300.aspx **4)**  http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php . If still having issues: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=install+php+5.4+windows+xp+iis . I did one of those few months back for a friend and it worked (personally I'm using IIS 7 on Windows 7, so installation is "a bit" different, as IIS 7 differs from IIS 6 and earlier).

Comment: P.S. Sorry, it was 5.3.x on Windows XP when I did it (installed from zip though) not 5.4.x.

Comment: if you are learning PHP .. I will suggest using xampp.. its much easier... you just have to download it unzio it - start the xampp control and you are ready...

Comment: @LazyOne, that worked great.  PHP is now running on my local machine.  Put that as an answer so I can Accept it, please.

Comment: I do not think that bunch of a simple links can be treated as a good answer. I suggest putting answer yourself -- you can tell what link was good for you and describe some hints/experience in general -- this will be much better answer in such situation.

Comment: I followed the instructions exactly and got the exact same successful results.  I don't know what else I could add to it, except that the answer you gave is good, and it answered the question exactly and precisely.  I don't know why you would downplay your participation in this way -- are you trying to avoid gaining reputation points?

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot simpler to use WAMP which comes with Apapche, MySQL and PHP bundled and already configured with eachother. http://www.wampserver.com/en/ you may need to enabled mod rewrite but again that's easy from the interface.

Comment: OK, this seems to work OK, except I would guess that running IIS and Apache on the same instance of Windows is not going to work. Because it doesn't. If I try to run the http://localhost, IIS takes over and runs instead.  Oh, and if I double click on a PHP file, Windows runs Expression Blend, of all things.

Comment: Yes you can't run both IIS and Apache they both run on port 80. I'm not familiar with IIS and dislike it in general. Drop IIS and go with WAMP IMO

Comment: "Drop IIS and go with WAMP"?  Sigh.  Nice idea in theory.  Unfortunately I am a Windows web dev in my professional position, and IIS is kinda heavily involved.  But your unfamiliarity with IIS doesn't justify your dislike, IMHO.  I am equally unfamiliar with Apache, yet have much respect for it, and my experience with IIS leads me to like it a lot.

Comment: Well I still dislike IIS. I don't like windows as a webserver, NGINX is already more popular than IIS and apache is probably the most popular. http://www.infoworld.com/t/application-servers/nginx-overtakes-microsoft-no-2-web-server-183079